# Enable scrolling of content in slide in panel on iPhone

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iphone, scroll

http://www.daneliandesigns.co.uk/BKS/

The form does not scroll down on iPhone (you have to click the [+] button to activate slide in panel). I have FullPage.js enabled and this is working well. The content in the second section is scrollable on mobile but when the slide in panel is activated you can no longer scroll down on iPhone.

I have tried the following CSS but to no avail:

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
.form-live, .nks-content, .fp-enabled body {
 overflow:visible!important;   
 overflow:scroll;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;
 z-index:9999999999999999999999!important;

}
}
```

I have also tried adding to normalScrollElements:

```
function(isResponsive){
normalScrollElements: '#S2', '.nks-content';
}
```

I am not sure this second solution would work considering the slide in panel is not part of the FullPage.js

I just want to be able to scroll the slide in content down to the SUBMIT button on mobile - namely - iPhone

Comment: That's the longest z-index I've ever seen.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this issue before and It was because there was no height set. Try setting height to 100% and see if that works

Comment: Thank you - which element would you suggest setting a height on?

Comment: The containing element that has the overflow attribute

Comment: No such luck - thank you thought. Really appreciate the help.

Comment: Wait i just realized! You're double setting the overflow attribute

Comment: I think you want to change your code to overflow-x: visible !important; and overflow-y: scroll;

Comment: `@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
.form-cover, #nks_cc_sidebar {
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch!important;
overflow-y: scroll;
overflow-x: visible;
overflow:scroll;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;
z-index:9999999;
height:100%!important;
}
}`

Comment: I went to your site and was poking around. To be completely honest this seems like more of a touch handler issue to me. It correctly scrolls when the touch event takes place on the sides of the container but not when trying to touch over the elements inside (the text and inputs).

Comment: Haha my best advice would be to back track a bit till it was working then! Sorry I can't help more but goodluck!